# Why do analysis books give proofs of the unboundedness of $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{N}$? Are they needed?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Many Real Analysis (Advanced Calculus) books give in one form or another a proof that $\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$ are unbounded (e.g. Tom Apostol Mathematical Analysis Thm 1.17, Spivak Calculus Thm pg 136). The proofs use the LUB Axiom of $\mathbb{R}$.

**Question**: If we are to talk about the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$, we have either constructed them (something along the lines of Zermelo-Frankel set theory) , or used an axiomatic treatment like the Peano Axioms together with an existence axiom (i.e. there exists a set with a successor function that satisfies the Peano Axioms).

Either way, if by construction, then we will have an infinite set. If by using Peano's approach, then $\mathbb{N}$ is infinite because the Peano Axioms ensure that every element has a successor, and two different elements can't have the same successor.

Thus, since the Naturals or Integers are required to construct the rationals, it seems to me that "infinity" is already assumed. So why do we need further proof based off of the more sophisticated LUB Axiom?

Comment: "unbounded" and "infinite" can be different.

Comment: "Infinite" and "unbounded in $\mathbb{R}$" are not at all the same thing.

Comment: Ah! of course! I feel silly. Thank you!

Comment: You need unboundedness of $\Bbb N$ in $\Bbb R$ (the Archimedean property) to prve things like $\lim_{n\to\infty}1/n=0$.

Comment: Well the proofs using lub property assume different axioms which deal with existence of $\mathbb{R} $ directly and then deal with $\mathbb{N} $ as special subset. Peano axioms don't come into play here.